# How to pass parameter to vue.js router in a method function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to send 'joke.id' as parameter to the router:

```
edit: function(joke) {
    this.$router.push({ '/edit/' + joke.id }); 
}
```

The relevant route is:

```
{path: '/edit/:id', component: editJoke, name: 'editJoke'},
```

However I get this in the console:

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

```
this.$router.push({ '/edit/' + joke.id }); 
  |                          ^
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for curly braces inside the `push` function. Your code should be like this:

```
this.$router.push('/edit/' + joke.id);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can pass parameters to the router by using this syntax:

```
edit: function(joke) {
    this.$router.push('/edit/' + joke.id)
}
```

If you have named your route you can use this syntax instead:

```
edit: function(joke) {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'edit', params: { id: joke.id }})
}
```

Read more about programmatic navigation with Vue Router [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here you go!

```
 this.$router.push({name: 'DESTINATION', params: {VAR1: 'VALUE1', VAR2:'VALUE2'}})
```

You can have as many parameters as you want as such.
You can also apply the same technique from your HTML components:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'DESTINATION', params: {VAR1: 'VALUE1', VAR2: 'VALUE2'}}" />
```

Only make sure the destination name is equivalent to the name you specified inside your routes.

You don't necessarily have to use router-link since most of the current components support the :to attribute, especially [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com).

Answer (score 3):

You have to bind your router params

```
<router-link :to="{name:'show.user',params:{id:user.id} }">your links</router-link>
```

and in your index router

```
path:'/user/:id'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use params you need to use name and not path:

```
<nuxt-link :to="{name: 'post-detail-id', params: { id:idPost } }">{{title}}</nuxt-link>
```

You can see the name for each route into .nuxt/router.js

REFRENCE LINK: [Solution](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1546#issuecomment-326267738)